RealityKit Plane detection rotation issues on Vision Pro
I'm trying to detect planes around me using realityKit. Following the documentation example I've set up a task that adds, updates and removes anchors of detected planes around me and places equally sized and rotated planes into my scene.
However when I run the app some of the planes are rotated wrong in the space. They are positioned correctly and have the correct size, but the rotation along the vertical axis is shifted by a few degrees. I've noticed all of the horizontal planes have this issue while none of the vertical ones do.
I compared this with the debug view that displays detected planes around me as wireframe.
To make it all more inconsistent, I've managed to get the planes to align correctly in a couple of cases after multiple restarts of the Vision Pro.
Here is how I create the entity:
private func createPlaneEntity( anchor: PlaneAnchor) -> Entity {
    let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: anchor.geometry.extent.width, depth: anchor.geometry.extent.height)
    let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .init(red: CGFloat.random(in: 0.0 ..< 1.0), green: CGFloat.random(in: 0.0 ..< 1.0), blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0.0 ..< 1.0), alpha: 0.5), isMetallic: false)
    let planeEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        
    planeEntity.setTransformMatrix(anchor.originFromAnchorTransform, relativeTo: nil)
    return planeEntity
}

Here is where I call the entity creation:
try await session.run([planeData])
isPlaneDetectionRunning = true
                
for await update in planeData.anchorUpdates {
    let planeAnchor = update.anchor
    switch update.event {
    case .added:
        self.planeAnchors.append(planeAnchor)
        let planeEntity = self.createPlaneEntity(anchor: planeAnchor)
        self.planeEntities[planeAnchor.id] = planeEntity
        sceneContent?.addChild(planeEntity)
                        
    case .updated:
        if let index = self.planeAnchors.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == planeAnchor.id }) {
            self.planeAnchors[index] = update.anchor
                if let planeEntity = self.planeEntities[planeAnchor.id] {
                    self.updatePlaneEntity(planeEntity, anchor: planeAnchor)
                }
            }
    case .removed:
        self.planeAnchors.removeAll(where: { $0.id == planeAnchor.id })
        if let planeEntity = self.planeEntities.removeValue(forKey: planeAnchor.id) {
            planeEntity.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}

I've compared the transforms of the detected anchors with the planes I'm putting into the scene, but they are identical.
